# C# design - How can I essentially group classes and enums in a list without an empty interface?

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns, interface

I am designing a text renderer. I am building the logic of how to split a string into lines to fit within the textbox. The way I would like to do this is by first splitting the full string into "Words", "Spaces" and "Newlines", then building an algorithm to measure how much can fit on one line before moving onto the next.

However, "Word" needs to be a class/struct because it wants to hold extra attributes such as "FontStyle", "Colour", etc. "Space" and "NewLine" are just markers - they don't need any data.

At the moment I have the following framework:

```
interface ILineComponent
{
}

struct Word : ILineComponent
{
    public string Text;
    public FontStyle Style;
    public Colour Colour;

    public Word(string text, FontStyle style, Colour colour)
    {
        Text = text;
        Style = style;
        Colour = colour;
    }
}

struct Space : ILineComponent
{
}

struct NewLine : ILineComponent
{
}

struct Line
{
    public List<ILineComponent> Segments;

    public Line(List<ILineComponent> segments)
    {
        Segments = segments;
    }
}
```

The idea then being I will go through the Line and measure how many (word,space,...,word,space) will fit on a line (or word,...,newline) before breaking it up to another line. At the moment this will utilise logic like:

```
foreach (ILineComponent component in line)
{
    if (component is Word)
    //..
    else if (component is Space)
    //...
    else if (component is NewLine)
    //...
}
```

But this design breaches [CA1040](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1040?view=vs-2019).

How could I design this better?

Comment: I think we can't come up with a better design until we know what happens inside the if/else statement. From your description, I guess you want to call something like `MeasureString()`. So, why not put `MeasureString()` into the interface?

Comment: @ThomasWeller newline doesn't have a size. I will only be measuring the Words, space has a defined size outside of here (coming from Font).

Comment: `return 0.0;` ?

Comment: but I would still have if (component is NewLine) - since that's a special case that means I break the line regardless of length

Comment: In the current structure, the algorithm is going to add increasing numbers of components until the line width is reached, or a newline is found. But space is also a special case because if a space is at the end of a line, it should be discounted from measurement, and removed from the rendering. Hence the need for "is" on both NewLine and Space, and .MeasureString() being insufficient.

Comment: You could put that into the interface as well. Everything returns string.Empty, NewLine returns `\r\n`.

Comment: What do you render to? HTML? Graphics?

Comment: I am using this logic to build openGL vertices to pull letters from a spritesheet and render to a texture. So I have no use for \r\n - I need to tell the vertices to start on the next line myself. Hence breaking this into a set of Lines myself.

Comment: Do you do two-pass rendering? E.g. for justification so that all lines have equal length, but the size of a space changes?

Comment: After I have a Line which has (Word,Space,Word,Space,Word) in it, I then have logic against my rendering class Text which uses an enum HAlignment (Left, Centred, Right, Full) which will determine whether the Space character uses the .ttf's default space width (the first three cases), or the spaces get distributed to fill the full text box (Full case).

Comment: You don't need `Space` - it's just another piece of text. You also don't need `NewLine` - one implicitly exists between lines

Comment: @StenPetrov: the `NewLine` is used to determine whether a new line should be started despite the fact that there is still room in the current line

Comment: @ThomasWeller @Haighstrom Take a look at OpenXML, it solves the problem and then some. See the XML structure under `<w:p>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraph?view=openxml-2.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty interface does not only violate CA1040. It also violates the clean code principle of DRY, because it is very likely that you will have those if/else statements in several places of the code. What else would you do with an empty interface, if not make some decisions based on its presence?

So yeah, let's get rid of it. Thanks for caring about compiler warnings and trying to write better code.

First of all, I think the definition of a `Space` is incomplete. The space cannot determine its width without also having a font. Thus I think the space should be similar to `Word`. Maybe it does not need a color, and it certainly does not need a text as argument.

```
struct Space : ILineComponent
{
    public readonly string Text = " ";
    public FontStyle Style;

    public Word(FontStyle style)
    {
        Style = style;
    }
}
```

I would not consider it as a special case of `Word`. And you'll see later, why that's the case. It's because of how I propose the interface.

Also I think this code is misleading

```
foreach (ILineComponent component in line)
```

Since you don't know yet, how many lines there will be, the variable `line` is not correct. This should be `componentsOfText` or similar. Inside the loop, you would start new lines whenever needed.

Next, I propose you put everything that these three components need to do into the interface. As far as I understood, that is:

```
interface ILineComponent
{
    int Measure();
    bool IsTrimmedAtEndOfLine;
    bool TerminatesLine;
}
```

For the `NewLine`, `Measure()` simply returns 0.

Your code then looks like this:

```
//       IList<LineComponent> is a line
// IList<       -"-          > are many lines
// Maybe you want to define an alias for that, or even a class
IList<IList<ILineComponent>> lines = new ...;

int remainingSpace = 2000; // px or whatever
while (componentsOfText.Length > 0)
{
     component = componentsOfText[0];

     var space = component.Measure();
     if (space > remainingSpace)
     {
          // finish current line and start a new one, 
          // i.e. add a new List<LineComponent>,
          // reset remaining space,
          // do the line post processing (e.g. space width adjustment)

          // Do not remove component from the list
          continue;
     }

     if (component.TerminatesLine)
     {
           // Finish current line and start a new line
           // just as before
     }

     remainingSpace -= space;
     componentsOfText.Remove(component);
}
```

For the part "finish current line and start a new one":

```
var lastitem = line[line.Count - 1];
if (lastitem.IsTrimmedAtEndOfLine)
{
    line.Remove(lastitem);
}

// start the second pass for calculating the width of a space etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I am trying out a couple of different options and will get back to you on if this works best or if I have any challenges for it. One issue I see is that I also need to measure partial words, because (uniquely) if the first word on a line consumes more than a full line, it should auto-wrap (by splitting it into two words). So I'm still in the bounds of "if current line is empty, and component is Word then...". But in general I see your point of how the interface could do with members - which move away from the use of "is".

Comment: I used your proposals to create what I needed, and [it's working](https://imgur.com/dWHyiQM). See my full code below, including the rendering code so you get the gist of how this works in full. Do you have any objection to my use of enums?

Answer (score 0):

I used Thomas's answer to help build something more robust.

Helper classes:

```
internal enum LineComponentType { Word, Space, NewLine }

internal interface ILineComponent
{
    float Length { get; }
    LineComponentType Type { get; }
    Colour Colour { get; }
}

internal class NewLine : ILineComponent
{
    public float Length => 0;
    public LineComponentType Type => LineComponentType.NewLine;
    public Colour Colour => Colour.Transparent;
}

internal class Space : ILineComponent
{
    public Space(HFont font, FontStyle fontStyle)
    {
        Length = font.MeasureString(' ', fontStyle).x;
    }

    public float Length { get; }

    public LineComponentType Type => LineComponentType.Space;
    public Colour Colour => Colour.Transparent;
    public override string ToString() => " ";
}

internal class Word : ILineComponent
{
    private readonly HFont _font;

    public Word(string text, HFont font, FontStyle style, Colour colour)
    {
        Text = text;
        _font = font;
        Style = style;
        Colour = colour;

        Length = font.MeasureString(text, style).x;
    }

    public float Length { get; }

    public LineComponentType Type => LineComponentType.Word;

    public string Text { get; }

    public FontStyle Style { get; }

    public Colour Colour { get; }

    public float MeasureCharAtIndex(int index) => _font.MeasureString(Text[index], Style).x;

    public Word SubWord(int startIndex) => new Word(Text.Substring(startIndex), _font, Style, Colour);

    public Word SubWord(int startIndex, int length) => new Word(Text.Substring(startIndex, length), _font, Style, Colour);

    public override string ToString() => Text;
}
```

Main class for rendering:

```
public class HText : IRectGraphic
{
    //...

    private List<List<ILineComponent>> SplitTextToLines(string text)
    {
        //Convert text into a list of IComponents
        var allComponents = new List<ILineComponent>();

        text.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
        text.Replace("\r", "\n");

        while (!text.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            if (text[0] == ' ')
            {
                allComponents.Add(new Space(Font, FontStyle));
                text = text.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            else if (text[0] == '\n')
            {
                allComponents.Add(new NewLine());
                text = text.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            else //it's a word
            {
                var words = text.Split(new[] { '\n', ' ' });
                allComponents.Add(new Word(words[0], Font, FontStyle, Colour));
                text = text.Remove(0, words[0].Length);
            }
        }

        var lines = new List<List<ILineComponent>>();

        //Split IComponents into lines
        var currentLine = new List<ILineComponent>();

        bool oneLetterWiderThanWholeLine = false;

        while (!allComponents.IsEmpty())
        {
            var component = allComponents[0];

            switch (component.Type)
            {
                case LineComponentType.Word:
                    var word = (Word)component;

                    if (currentLine.Sum(c => c.Length) + word.Length <= w) //if it fits, add it to the current line
                    {
                        //if we started a new line with a space then a word, remove the space
                        if (lines.Count != 0 && currentLine.Count == 1 && currentLine[0].Type == LineComponentType.Space)
                            currentLine.RemoveAt(0);

                        currentLine.Add(component);
                        allComponents.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                    else if (currentLine.Count == 0) //if doesn't fit, but it is the first word in a line, we will split and wrap it
                    {
                        int splitAt = 0;
                        float width = 0;

                        float nextCharLength;
                        while (width + (nextCharLength = word.MeasureCharAtIndex(splitAt)) <= w)
                        {
                            width += nextCharLength;
                            splitAt++;
                        }

                        if (splitAt == 0) //if one letter is too wide to fit, display it anyway
                        {
                            splitAt = 1;
                            oneLetterWiderThanWholeLine = true;
                        }

                        var word1 = word.SubWord(0, splitAt);
                        var word2 = word.SubWord(splitAt);

                        currentLine.Add(word1);
                        lines.Add(currentLine);
                        currentLine = new List<ILineComponent>();
                        allComponents.RemoveAt(0);
                        allComponents.Insert(0, word2);
                    }
                    else //push the word to the next line
                    {
                        lines.Add(currentLine);
                        currentLine = new List<ILineComponent>();
                        //we don't add the next word to the next line yet - it might not fit
                    }
                    break;

                case LineComponentType.Space:
                    if (currentLine.Sum(c => c.Length) + component.Length > w)
                    {
                        lines.Add(currentLine);
                        currentLine = new List<ILineComponent>();
                    }
                    currentLine.Add(component);
                    allComponents.RemoveAt(0);
                    break;

                case LineComponentType.NewLine:
                    lines.Add(currentLine);
                    currentLine = new List<ILineComponent>();
                    allComponents.RemoveAt(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new HException("Htext/SplitTextToLines: Unhandled component type {0}", component.Type);
            }
        }

        if (currentLine.Count > 0)
            lines.Add(currentLine);

        //Size warnings
        if (lines.Count * Font.BiggestChar.y > h)
            HConsole.Log("HText/SetVertices: lines total height ({0}) is bigger than text box height ({1})", lines.Count * Font.BiggestChar.y, h);

        if (oneLetterWiderThanWholeLine)
            HConsole.Log("HText/SetVertices: a single letter is beyond the text box width ({0})", w);

        return lines;
    }

    private void SetVertices()
    {
        var vertices = new List<Vertex>();

        var lines = SplitTextToLines(Text);

        var dest = new Rect();

        switch (VAlignment)
        {
            case VAlignment.Top:
                dest.y = 0;
                break;
            case VAlignment.Centre:
                dest.y = (h - lines.Count * Font.BiggestChar.y) / 2;
                break;
            case VAlignment.Bottom:
                dest.y = h - lines.Count * Font.BiggestChar.y;
                break;
            case VAlignment.Fill:
                dest.y = 0;
                break;
            default:
                throw new HException("HText/SetVertices: alignment {0} was not catered for.", VAlignment);
        }

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            switch (HAlignment)
            {
                case HAlignment.LeftJustified:
                    dest.x = 0;
                    break;
                case HAlignment.Centred:
                    dest.x = (w - line.Sum(c => c.Length)) / 2;
                    break;
                case HAlignment.RightJustified:
                    dest.x = w - line.Sum(c => c.Length);
                    break;
                case HAlignment.FullyJustified:
                    dest.x = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new HException("HText/SetVertices: alignment {0} was not catered for.", HAlignment);
            }

            foreach (var com in line)
                foreach (char c in com.ToString())
                {
                    var source = Font.CharPositionsNormalised[System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular][c];
                    dest.w = Font.CharPositions[System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular][c].w;
                    dest.h = Font.CharPositions[System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular][c].h;

                    vertices.Add(HF.Geom.QuadToTris(
                        new Vertex(dest.TopLeft, com.Colour, source.TopLeft),
                        new Vertex(dest.TopRight, com.Colour, source.TopRight),
                        new Vertex(dest.BottomLeft, com.Colour, source.BottomLeft),
                        new Vertex(dest.BottomRight, com.Colour, source.BottomRight)
                        ));

                    dest.x += dest.w;
                }
            dest.y += Font.BiggestChar.y;
        }

        _vertices = vertices.ToArray();
    }

    public virtual void Render(ref Matrix4 projection, ref Matrix4 modelView)
    {
        if (w == 0 || h == 0)
            return;

        if (HV.LastBoundTexture != Texture.ID)
        {
            OpenGL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, Texture.ID);
            HV.LastBoundTexture = Texture.ID;
        }

        if (HV.LastBoundVertexBuffer != VertexBuffer)
            Bind();

        if (_verticesChanged)
        {
            SetVertices();
            _verticesChanged = false;

            OpenGL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertices.Length * Vertex.STRIDE, _vertices, BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);
        }

        var mv = Matrix4.Translate(ref modelView, x, y, 0);

        Shader.Render(ref projection, ref mv, _vertices.Length, PrimitiveType.Triangles);
    }
}
```